# 'launch' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use launchUrl instead. - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Following all tutorials and articles online, everybody is using `launch()` function from the known url_launcher plugin to open links, so i used it in my application to open messenger, whatsApp, and directcalls as follows:

```
_directCall() {
    launch('tel:00962785522213');
  }

  //Open WhatsApp
  _launchWhatsapp() {
    launch("https://wa.me/+962797809910");
  }

  //Open Messenger
  _openMessenger() {
    launch("http://m.me/amr.al.shugran");
  }
```

but unfortunately the launch method is no longer used and i have to use `launchUrl()` so i would be thankful if anyone could tell us how to use this function at the same context am using `launch()`.

Comment: It works just like `launch` but now just change it to `launchUrl(url)`

Comment: i surely tried that but it didn't work simply it shows an error that it doesn't take a string value.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `launchUrl(Uri.parse(yourStringValue))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
 //Open Messenger
  _openMessenger() {
    launchUrl(Uri.parse("http://m.me/amr.al.shugran"));
  }
```

Comment: after using the solution i get this :  The webpage at intent://user/562084722.?intent_trigger=mme#intent;scheme=fb-messenger;package=com.facebook.orca;end could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_UNKOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: That's a different error, it has to do with the format of your url. The solution to your question is using launchUrl+uri.parse. If you put in `https://google.com` it would open. Please post the new problem in a separate question and if your issue is resolved here kindly mark it as accepted.

Comment: true, thanks ill mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
Future _launchUrl(url) async {
    if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          _launchUrl('www.google.com');
        },
        child: const Text('Open'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: i actually having the same error for the previous answer:

 after using the solution i get this : The webpage at intent://user/562084722.?intent_trigger=mme#intent;scheme=fb-messenger;package=com.facebook.orca;end could not be loaded because: net::ERR_UNKOWN_URL_SCHEME